# Saying something like it is

Tags: word-request

What do you call a smart man who says things like they are without being diplomatic or PC. I'm looking for a word that have a positive meaning.

Comment: Many people will say that to be "not PC" can never be "positive", and thus this question is asking for opinion-based answers.

Comment: If you edit your question to give an example of a sentence where you want to use this word, and explain what words you have considered and rejected, it might cause some people to upvote or possibly undo their downvote.

Answer (score 2):

The person can be called **forthright**. Lexico (Oxford Dictionaries) has [this](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/forthright)

> **forthright**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> **1** (of a person or their manner or speech) direct and outspoken.
>
> *The most honest, honorable, forthright people in my life are also polite, compassionate, and quite capable of making constructive criticism.*

A **forthright** person says things that need to be said, which might be non-PC, but does not cause offence for its own sake, or to be cruel. So in that sense, it is a positive description of someone.

This answer is not intended to be a value judgement on political correctness.

Comment: Why are the question and the answers being downvoted?

Comment: @Paracosmiste I think it's because some of these people think they have an obligation to tell you how they feel about your (presumed) attitude (based on how you used the expression "PC").

Answer (score 2):

direct

> : NATURAL, STRAIGHTFORWARD
>   a direct manner
>   asked him to be more direct
>   was direct in her criticism

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/direct

frank

> : marked by free, forthright, and sincere expression
>   a frank reply

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frank

These words can also refer to women.

Comment: Sometimes such a man (or woman!) can be called something less complimentary, especially if they are routinely and vocally "non-PC".